# oledb error '80040e14' whit [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: asp-classic

In my Classic asp application I am trying to generate a web report and getting following error message:

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14' 
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '='. 
/rpts/displayreporthtml.asp, line 13

The above error message is coming only for some cases like when record count is more than 5000 and the record count is not fixed, I mean I am geting this error for 5432, 5442, etc. number of records.

**in Global.asa**

---

```
Dim LTConn
set LTConn=Server.CreateObject("adodb.connection")
LTConn.CommandTimeout=5000
LTConn.ConnectionTimeout=5000
LTConn.Open "DSN=xx;uid=sa;pwd=password"
```

---

### **in respective page**

```
myquery = "select   k.* from ("&myquery&")k where " & request("filterText") 
set rs=DBConn.execute (myquery)
```

---

Please guide me to resolve the issue.

Thanks,

Comment: post some codes. that'd be useful to understand the problem

Comment: Can we see the SQL command being send to the DB?

Comment: Something in your SQL is wrong. Do `Response.Write(myquery)` to see the   actual SQL (instead of executing it) and if you still can't figure what's wrong post it here and we'll try to guide you further. Please use `@` to notify once you do this otherwise we won't get any notification.

Comment: Never EVER EVER trust user input...this code is bad `request("filterText")`

Comment: Just for your info, the query is working perfectly and it gives around 24K records in backend. I have noticed page breaks after 5K records for any kind of query.

Comment: Just to follow up on @Sean's comment - you should never ever do this because it opens you up to SQL injection attacks.  If you don't know what they are, take the time to read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1):

In your global.asa you create a connection string called `LTConn`
In your retrieval page it seems the you call on a connection with the name `DBConn`. 
Shouldn't your query call on `LTConn` instead of `BDConn`?